# boost range adaptor that makes a collection

Tags: c++, boost, boost-range, boost-adaptors

I want to write a boost adaptor to put at the end of a chain of adaptors to create a collection, like this:

```
set<string> s = input | filtered(...) | transformed(...) | to_set;
```

Using [Method 3.1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_3/method_3_1.html) I wrote the code below which seems to work as expected:

```
namespace detail
{
    struct to_set_forwarder
    {
    };
};

template <class R> inline auto operator|(R& r, detail::to_set_forwarder)
{
    return set<R::value_type>(r.begin(), r.end());
}

template <class R> inline auto operator|(const R& r, detail::to_set_forwarder)
{
    return set<const R::value_type>(r.begin(), r.end());
}

namespace
{
    const auto to_set = detail::to_set_forwarder();
}

void F()
{
    vector<string> input{ "1", "2", "3" };
    auto result = input
        //| boost::adaptors::filtered([](const auto& _) { return true; })
        | to_set;
}
```

But if I uncomment that one line, I get:

> error C2338: The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator is ill-formed.

If I make the first parameter to `operator|` be `&&` then that works until I uncomment the `filtered()` line, and then I get:

> error C2825: 'R': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Like it says, standard containers cannot store const elements. Neither do you want to (because you store copies anyways. If you wanted them const, you can make the container `const`).

The fix is:

```
template <class R> inline auto operator|(const R& r, detail::to_set_forwarder)
{
    return std::set<typename R::value_type>(r.begin(), r.end());
}
```

(removing `const`).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/398b59bc30c88deb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace detail
{
    struct to_set_forwarder
    {
    };
}

template <class R> inline auto operator|(R& r, detail::to_set_forwarder)
{
    return std::set<typename R::value_type>(r.begin(), r.end());
}

template <class R> inline auto operator|(const R& r, detail::to_set_forwarder)
{
    return std::set<typename R::value_type>(r.begin(), r.end());
}

namespace
{
    const auto to_set = detail::to_set_forwarder();
}

void F()
{
    std::vector<std::string> input{ "1", "2", "3", "2" };
    auto result = input
        | boost::adaptors::filtered([](const auto& _) { return true; })
        | to_set;

    for (auto x : result)
        std::cout << x << " ";
}

int main() {
    F();
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3
```

---

PS: You are missing `typename` qualifications (try another compiler than MSVC sometimes)

PS: You can `boost::copy_range`:

```
auto result = boost::copy_range<std::set<std::string> >(input
    | boost::adaptors::filtered([](const auto& _) { return true; })
    );
```